error 403 forbiden After Login in codeigniter
I have an error after login page, I'm using username and password and get error 403
This is my controller
public function index()
{
    
    $valid=$this->form_validation;
    $valid->set_rules('username','Username','required',array('required' => '%s Harus Diisi' ));
    $valid->set_rules('password','Password','required',array('required' => '%s Harus Diisi' ));

    if ($valid->run($this)) {
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        //prosess ke simple_login

        $this->user_login->login($username,$password);
        
        }
    $data = array(
                    'title' => 'Login',
                    'desa'      =>$this->m_home->desa(),
                    );
    $this->load->view('v_login', $data, FALSE);
}

